# csquotes messes up babel language selection for printing bibliography

Tags: biblatex, babel, csquotes

In the following example, enabling the csquotes packages wrongly uses German quotation marks in the bibliography, although I told babel that this is English:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish,german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} % !
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,citestyle=verbose-ibid,isbn=false,maxnames=3,bibstyle=authoryear,useprefix=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex} % citereset=chapter

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib} 
@phdthesis{rutz2014tracing,
    AUTHOR      = {Rutz, Hanns Holger},
    TITLE       = {Tracing the Compositional Process. Sound art that rewrites its own past: formation, praxis and a computer framework},
    SCHOOL      = {Plymouth University},
    ADDRESS     = {UK},
    YEAR        = {2014},
    URL         = {http://hdl.handle.net/10026.1/3116}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\selectlanguage{UKenglish}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{german}
\section*{Publikationen}

Alle unter "`Open Access"' verfügbaren Publikationen sind unter ... verlinkt.

\selectlanguage{UKenglish}
\nocite{rutz2014tracing}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

As soon as I remove the csquotes packages, the quotes correctly return to English:

[image]

How do I fix this while keeping the csquotes package enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the option `autostyle` to csquotes. Comment aside: the image in your post shows American quotes rather than British ones.

*Note:* You also may have quotes in the references sections established on a per entry language basis if  you use the `langid` field.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage[UKenglish,german]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes} % !
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,citestyle=verbose-ibid,isbn=false,maxnames=3,bibstyle=authoryear,useprefix=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex} % citereset=chapter

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib}
@phdthesis{rutz2014tracing,
    AUTHOR = {Rutz, Hanns Holger},
    TITLE = {Tracing the Compositional Process. Sound art that rewrites its own past: formation, praxis and a computer framework},
    SCHOOL = {Plymouth University},
    ADDRESS = {UK},
    YEAR = {2014},
    URL = {http://hdl.handle.net/10026.1/3116}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\selectlanguage{UKenglish}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{german}
\section*{Publikationen}

Alle unter "`Open Access"' verfügbaren Publikationen sind unter ... verlinkt.

\selectlanguage{UKenglish}
\nocite{rutz2014tracing}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]